# Switching to ipython for python3?

Tags: python, ipython

I have python 2.7 and python3 installed on my machine along with ipython. I wanna use Ipython with python3 by default its taking python 2.7. Whats the Process to use ipython with python 3.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374675/ipython3-for-mac-osx.  `pip3 install ipython[all]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why don't you try this:

```
ipython3
```

Comment: I tried this its not working it says The program 'ipython3' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ipython3
I did the install its working fine now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had to apt-get install ipython3, on Linux Mint, which is similar to Debian and Ubuntu.

If you're on a Redhat-like OS, you may have something similar for yum.

Comment: Yups I also had to do the same.After installation its working fine.